# Android passing object to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a message class

```
class Message
{
    public String message, sender;
    public Message (String msg, String from)
    {
        message = msg;
        sender = from;
    }
    public String toString () { return sender+":"+message; }
}
```

I defined a table variable for use this class in main activity:

```
Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>> table = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Message>>();
```

I am adding data in main activity to message class with this code:

```
table.put("user01", new ArrayList<Message>());
table.get("user01").add(new Message("message","sender"));
```

And I want to use this table variable in another fragment.I am passing with this code to fragment.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ConversationFragment conv = new ConversationFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, conv);
        ConversationFragment frgObj=ConversationFragment.newInstance(table.get("user01"));
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, frgObj,"ConversationFragment");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And this is newInstance function in Conversation fragment

```
static int myData;
public static ConversationFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Message> _extractedMessages){
    ConversationFragment fragment = new ConversationFragment();
myData=_extractedMessages.size();
return  fragment;
}
```

But I am getting nullpointer exception,for _extractedMessages.size().

This code is working

```
System.out.println(_extractedMessages);
```

But this is not working

```
System.out.println(_extractedMessages.size());
```

Ps:I can use size function in main activity,I can't use only in conversation fragment.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure table.get("user01")is not null?

Comment: Yes I am sure it is not null

Comment: Use Fragment.getArguments() to carry fragment arguments. These arguments will survive when orientation changed too. You also consider to implement Java Serializable OR Android Parcelable interface for your value objects.

Comment: @LocHa can you give an example for me ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you pass parameters to the fragment in the Bundle *(and make sure the Message class implements Parcelable)*:

```
public static ConversationFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Message> _extractedMessages){    
    ConversationFragment fragment = new ConversationFragment();   

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(KEY_MESSAGES, _extractedMessages);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return  fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myData = getArguments().getParcelable(KEY_MESSAGES);
}
```

Comment: In order to do this OP should also implement `Parcelable` interface in his `Message` class.