# Passing Fragment some variable best practices

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have seen this done two ways, the most common being with arguments and passing it through the bundle as mentioned in this SO answer

[Android passing object to fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316040/android-passing-object-to-fragment)

```
public static ConversationFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Message> _extractedMessages){    
    ConversationFragment fragment = new ConversationFragment();   

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(KEY_MESSAGES, _extractedMessages);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return  fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myData = getArguments().getParcelable(KEY_MESSAGES);
}
```

I do not recall where, but I have also seen another pattern that seems to me to be more optimized as it doesnt require any bundle. Can you find a reason as to why I should not use this pattern instead?

```
   public static ConversationFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Message> _extractedMessages){    
        ConversationFragment fragment = new ConversationFragment();   
        fragment.myData = _extractedMessages;        
        return  fragment;
    }

    ArrayList<Message> myData;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setArguments(Bundle bundle)` from the docs:

> Supply the construction arguments for this fragment. This can only be
>   called before the fragment has been attached to its activity; that is,
>   you should call it immediately after constructing the fragment. **The
>   arguments supplied here will be retained across fragment destroy and
>   creation.**

So if your Fragment is destroyed and recreated by Android (for some reason), you will be able to keep your data if you use setArguments().

Comment: Gotcha, I suppose I can see how the second way would render my variable null if the frag was rectreated by the system - orientation change is the only thing that comes to mind.

Comment: @r2DoesInc That, or if your app is in the background for a while, and Android needs to kill off the fragment to reclaim memory. Also, it's not good to expose your internal data structure and access it that way (you could possibly have a setData() method as long as the fragment handles saving it in onSaveInstanceState()) but yeah, I prefer the newInstance method myself.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the variable telling that you are trying to provide a list of messages for the `ConversationFragment`. The first approach is bad idea to put large amount of data in bundle. (since bundle size limitation is 500k (or 1Mb)). I suggest that you pull the data from you source (database usually) in the `ConversationFragment` itself. And if you are using database its highly recommended to use [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) with [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/CursorLoader.html) with is very good with specially is you want to load data into listview. But using `ContentProvider` is a little tricky at first.

Comment: None of that is my code. I took the sample from another SO question. The data is irrelevant to what I am asking, as I am only generically curious as to passing data.